# Looking for an image viewer program that supports vertical scrolling

Tags: windows, image-viewer

Is there something that will let open a folder of images (.jpg) and scroll through them vertically? I.E. by using the up/down arrow keys, in an effect similar to if they were loaded into a PDF or powerpoint format?

I am looking for a windows solution, FLOSS is preferred if it exists.

Comment: Is the Windows native _Photo Viewer_ not an option?

Comment: @rrirower not unless it can scroll through images via the up/down keys

Comment: It uses the left and right arrow keys. Still not an option?

Comment: @rrirower not unless it's can be configured to do so without re-mapping the left/right arrow keys to up/down

Comment: He's talking about an image viewer which doesn't show you 1 single image on the screen which then you have to switch to the next one via clicking,
but instead loads all the images in the folder stacked vertically so you are basically scrolling down from one image to the next like scrolling through a webpage, like a film reel.
I asked the Honeyview devs to implement this feature, but whether it will happen is a big question. I'm also trying to find a neat simple image viewer like this which doesn't eat performance and also can load up rar/zip/cbr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about packing folder as zip (preferably in copy = no compression mode) to file with .cbz extension? You can open it then with comic book readers, e.g. SumatraPDF (open source) and these application are specialized in browsing multiple images.

Comment: This works great, thanks! (P.S. - I used 7zip for the copy/no-compression mode to zip archive for anyone wondering)

Comment: Additional note: you may try CbxConverter reduce size (useful e.g. for mobile readers) of cbz files (usually more than few times) by scaling down images and converting them to WebP (this format works great with graphics, it may not be as good is photos). Keep the original files if their content is unique/valuable - recompression to lossy format would degrade quality a bit.

Comment: now you made me want a [mobile version](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20498/looking-for-and-android-cbz-file-reader-with-infinite-scrolling) - I haven't really had any performance/space issues yet, so I haven't worked with compressing them much

Comment: Any solution for macOS? Even on Windows SumatraPDF is the "only" solution available. And macOS doesn't seems have an equivalent.

Comment: @Ksec There is a dozen or two comic book readers for Windows. I don't know about MacOS, but quick search returns SimpleComic, yacreader, comical, DrawnStrips.

Comment: @TMSZ Thanks for the replay but I tried all of those before. And none of them support vertical continuous scrolling. The closest thing was YARCreader.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.de/), opens pretty much every image file format. If a folder contains more the one image you can use "left" and "right" arrow keys to view the files.

Or do you want to preview all of the files in a folder? Stick to windows explorer using ctrl+mouse wheel to enlarge the thumbnails ;-)

Comment: Looking for up and down arrows, not left and right

Comment: IrfanView also comes with a "Thumbnails" app to preview pictures in folders like Windows Explorer

Answer (score 1):

They're talking about continuous scrolling, which is something most image viewers don't have. If you don't mind a minor bug (easily cleared by going to windowed mode and back to fullscreen mode by pressing the F key twice) then PickWalker4.2 is fine, though Kaspersky being oversensitive as it is will think it's malware, when it's just due to old programming methods.

Answer (score 1):

PDF XChange Editor from Tracker Software, you can select and right-click files in windows explorer and "combine in PDF Viewer".

It opens multiple image (convert them) in a single PDF file

Intended to be done with PDF file but can be done with almost anything, like Word, Excel, image file, etc.

Can be slow if images are high res.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot and detail the steps to open all images of a folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/luejerry/html-mangareader

This is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer!  Can you please expand on it to explain how it meets the OP's requirements?

Answer (score 1):

PicWalker 4.2 http://www.completelyfreesoftware com/software/pwalk42.exe

or https://github.com/luejerry/html-mangareader

or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/manga-reader/lenpmadeeejkiiakkfodkpakhnegmlcb

Comment: A little more description would be appreciated, this is currently just a collection of links

Answer (score 1):

If you know a bit of programming and HTML, then you can write a loop to put the absolute path of each image in an `<img>` tag. Then save it all in an index.html file. Since Chrome browser can do vertical scrolling, I wrote this Python script. Run the script: `python createhtml.py`

https://pastebin.com/n7EWCWZJ

Answer (score 1):

Finally found one that works on macOS. ( Paid ) As a matter of fact this is probably the only one that works for WebToons / WebComics ( Comics that uses infinite vertical scrolls ) , paid or not.[1]

There are other solution such as YARCreader, but they provide scrolling "per image". So infinite scrolls only scrolls to the next image and the reading experience isn't very WebComic like.

EdgeView works like stitching all images within a folder into one long image. Just  how is it suppose to be like when reading WebComic on your Phone or Web.

Not affiliate in any way. I had to spend hours looking for an answer to similar question. Hope this helps.

[1] EdgeView - https://apps.apple.com/us/app/edgeview-2/id1206246482?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

There is a Windows program supporting vertical scroll.
https://vertical-scroller.website
You can control scroll speed, image size etc.. 
Check it out.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be free as it mentions a 14-day free trial, and I am a bit skeptical as to the website which is only in half-English..

Comment: No. It is free only for 14 days.

Comment: I use the software. No virus. There are different definitions of vertical scrolling so I think  it is necessary to try it. Supports continous vertical scrolling.  Scrolls images like a film reel.

Comment: @user2813274: The question does not say solutions must be gratis. @ kiyoshi kohiyama: Could you please add a screenshot and detail the steps to open all images of a folder?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I did specify that I would prefer a [FLOSS solution](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/floss-and-foss.en.html) - id prefer answers at least mention if they aren't

Comment: @kiyoshikohiyama: Please also mention what are the terms of usage of this solution: Free period, price afterwards, limitations, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This application works great for scrolling 1 large vertical image, its super easy to use, you can add music, intro & outro clips as well, its called My Scrolls

https://smart-games-production.itch.io/my-scrolls

I hope thats what you are looking for?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).