# Looking for and Android cbz file reader with infinite scrolling

Tags: android, image-viewer, reading

I am looking for an app (FLOSS preferred) that will display .cbz files with "infinite scrolling" - i.e. similar to what some book reader/pdf apps will do where you aren't going "page by page" but can instead scroll "line by line" through the entire document.

Is there anything that will let me do that in android, but with images instead of text? (i.e. you can see the bottom half of one image and the top half of the next one at the same time, without it being in a transitional phase only)?

Bonus points for if it can be configured to "move" through the images via the volume buttons (up/down) as opposed to swiping

Comment: I think you are asking for **incremental** scrolling rather than infinite.

Comment: @SteveBarnes it depends, sometimes it's called continuous (adobe PDF reader for example), sometime incremental, and other times infinite (like facebook's "timeline"), where the concept of "pages" is removed

Comment: I'm not reading comics, but rather epub and sometimes PDF – so my list of [eBook Reader](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/reading_ebookreaders) apps for Android has those CBZ rather as "side-effect". But there are several, not all of them mentioning CBZ explicitly (I e.g. use *MoonReader Pro*, which definitely supports the scrolling you asked for with epub, but not with PDF; so I'm not sure whether that scrolling is supported with CBZ there, though the format itself is supported).

Answer (score 4):

[Challenger Comics Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kill.geek.bdviewer&hl=en) allows you to scroll incrementally as well as page by page, (I think that is what you are really asking for), so that more than one image is visible on the page at a time.

- Supported formats are JPG, PNG, GIF, WebP (Android 4.0+), BMP, PDF, CBZ/ZIP,CBR/RAR and ePUB
- Free
- 2 display modes (Simple View which displays pages one by one and Multiple Image View which displays all pages one after the other)

[image: Screenshot from site]

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of cbz readers and found only two apps that do this: [Xodo PDF Reader & Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader) and [Challenger Comics Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kill.geek.bdviewer).

Of the two, I prefer Xodo as it has a modern design and in general feels more responsive. Challenger does seem to have more in the way of customisation, though.